# how can we cancel downloading task started by downloadManager

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager, download-manager

I have done this code for download progress bar but i also want to cancel that downloading task if user accidentally clicked on button. i am unable to achieve this thing .can anyone please help me out of this.

Tip: i am new to android java so please explain it with all detailed answer.thanks in advance..

```
String url = "URL";
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.setDescription("Some descrition");
            request.setTitle("Some title");

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            }
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "PDF_demo.ext");

            DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            if (manager != null) {
                long downloadID = manager.enqueue(request);

            }
```

Comment: Check the [`remove`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#remove(long...)) method. Sounds like it should do what you want.

Comment: @Tigger yes thanks but i want to call that method on the click of that notification.how can we achieve that thing?

Comment: So many different ways. You could make `DownloadManager manager` a global and reference / access `manager` from the click method. Personally, I would make a download `class`. If needed, I would make it a `static class`, but now you are moving in to a _how do I write code_ type of question.

Comment: @Tigger can i add cancel button in notification created by downloadManager?

Answer (score 0):

From [the document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#remove(long...)), try to use:

```
DownloadManager.remove(downloadID)
```

Comment: thank you brother , but i need to call this method on click on that specific notification how can i achieve this?